# operation region for MOSFET amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I have to bias the following circuit:

[image]

would the MOSFET need to operate in the linear region or the saturation region?

Comment: It might operate in both depending on your input signal amplitude range.

Comment: "`would the MOSFET need to operate in the linear region or the saturation region?`" That depends if you want your FET to behave more like a voltage controlled current source or more of a voltage controlled resistor...